# DOS Multiline batch command. How to add comments between arguments?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd, command-line-arguments

Id like to add comments like this:

```
makecert -r ^        // This means SelfSigned
         -pe ^       // Private key is exportable
         -a sha512 ^ // The algoritm
         ...
```

Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing official, but there is a simple and very effective hack - use undefined variables. At least one `=` is added to guarantee that the content cannot be a valid variable name, since the character cannot be used in a variable name. I use one at the beginning and end just for symmetry. Also, the comment cannot contain `%` or `:`. Finally, the line continuation `^` character must be the last character in the line.

```
makecert -r        %= This means SelfSigned     =% ^
         -pe       %= Private key is exportable =% ^
         -a sha512 %= The algoritm              =% ^
         ...
```

Note - this only works within a batch script. It cannot be used on the command line.

Comment: And it's also possible to put the comment just behin the caret. Like `makecert -r    ^%= My comment =%`

Comment: @jeb, yes, as long as there is no space between `^` and `%= comment =%`. Probably safer to recommend that `^` be at the end.

Comment: You're right. It's safer to place the caret at the end to avoid accidencially problems